# Python string comparison doesn't seem to be working

Tags: python, string, comparison

First of all, I am pulling in an intensity that's assigned to a clientID from a text file, once I have that intensity, I am storing it as clientIntensityResult and then depending on whether it's equal to High or Moderate, it should print out the corresponding list, yet my comparison in the if statement doesn't seem to be working? I have changed it to x = 1, if x == 1: and that works but there is something I'm missing in this string comparison?

```
def clientSelect():
    clientIntensity = open("clientIntensity.txt", "r") #opens file

    high = ["Running", "Swimming", "Aerobics", "Football", "Tennis"]
    moderate = ["Walking", "Hiking", "Cleaning", "Skateboarding", "Basketball"]

    searchId = input("Please enter a clientID (ffsss): ") #search string

    for line in clientIntensity:
        if re.match(searchId, line):
            clientIntensityResult = (line[6:])
            print ("Client intensity is: ", clientIntensityResult)

            if clientIntensityResult == "High":
                print (high)
            elif clientIntensityResult == "Moderate":
                print (moderate)
            else:
                print ("Nothing found")
```

Comment: NeQua,High
ImKol,Moderate
YoTri,Moderate
RoDen,High
NaThe,Moderate
ReWes,Moderate
BrFre,High
KaDat,High
ViRil,High
TrGeo,High

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You defined your variable as

```
clientIntensityResult = (line[6:])
```

Since you are iterating line by line, each string will have a `'\n'` on the end of it. You could do

```
clientIntensityResult = line.strip()[6:]
```

Then the rest should work.

Comment: Thank you, this is the answer I've been looking for! I even looked at the type and it returned as str and so thought nothing more to look further into realizing there was a \n rendering the comparison false